# Переназначение аппаратных кнопок android(java)

Tags: java, android, button

Я знаю метод для обработки нажатия кнопки Back, есть ли похожие методы для остальных аппаратных кнопок(меню, центральная кнопка, кнопки громкости, кнопка блокировки)?

Answer (score 1):

Не хочется забирать себе лавры другого человека, поэтому вот ссылка 
http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/keyboard.php

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onUserLeaveHint() {
    //Кнопка HOME
    super.onUserLeaveHint();
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    switch (keyCode) {
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU:
        //Кнопка меню
        return true;
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
        //Кнопка увеличения звука
        return true;
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
        //Кнопка уменьшения звука
        return false;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```